How to parallelize/speed up embarrassingly parallel numba code?
I have the following code:
@nb.njit(cache=True)
def find_two_largest(arr):
    # Initialize the first and second largest elements
    if arr[0] >= arr[1]:
        largest = arr[0]
        second_largest = arr[1]
    else:
        largest = arr[1]
        second_largest = arr[0]

    # Iterate through the array starting from the third element
    for num in arr[2:]:
        if num > largest:
            second_largest = largest
            largest = num
        elif num > second_largest:
            second_largest = num
    return largest, second_largest


@nb.njit(cache=True)
def max_bar_one(arr):
    largest, second_largest = find_two_largest(arr)
    missing_maxes = np.empty_like(arr)
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        if arr[i] == largest:
            if largest != second_largest:
                missing_maxes[i] = second_largest
            else:
                missing_maxes[i] = largest  # largest == second_largest
        else:
            missing_maxes[i] = largest
    return missing_maxes


@nb.njit(cache=True)
def replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last(d):
    """
    Run max_bar_one on each row but the last, prepend an all -inf row
    """
    m, n = d.shape
    result = np.empty((m, n))
    result[0] = -np.inf
    for i in range(0, m - 1):
        result[i + 1, :] = max_bar_one(d[i, :])
    return result


@nb.njit(cache=True)
def main_function(d, subcusum, j):
    temp = replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last(d)
    for i1 in range(temp.shape[0]):
        for i2 in range(temp.shape[1]):
            temp[i1, i2] = max(temp[i1, i2], d[i1, i2]) + subcusum[j, i2]
    return temp

I then set up the data with:
n = 5000
A = np.random.randint(-3, 4, (n, n)).astype(float)
cusum_rows = np.cumsum(A, axis=1)
rowseq = np.arange(n)
d = np.random.randint(-3, 4, (5000, 5000))

We can then time it with:
%timeit main_function(d, cusum_rows, 0)
166 ms ± 1.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Is it possible to parallelize the for loop or the code in general to speed this up? I tried using parallel=True in  replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last
but it didn't speed up the code and only reported:
Instruction hoisting:
loop #1:
  Failed to hoist the following:
    dependency: $value_var.73 = getitem(value=_72call__function_11, index=$parfor__index_72.90, fn=<built-in function getitem>)

This is surprising as all the calls in the for loop are independent.
Can this code be sped up and/or parallelized?

you have to use numba.prange  for parallel=True to have an effect, did you replace the range before timing it?

@Nin17 Actually that does give some speed up.

I wonder if your setup is realistic. With that range and size, the probability of second_largest not being 3 is less than 1e-330.

@ken That's a very interesting point! In practice they will be from a larger range but I wanted to make the example easy to debug.

While the code can be parallelized, a naive parallelization with the current input arrays will not be efficient. Indeed, the arrays are quite massive compared to the execution time causing the computation to be memory-bound (parallelism does not help much in this case). The input dtypes are float64 and int64 (int32 on Windows) while they only hold very small values. This seems a huge waste of resources to me (space and time). Can't much smaller type be used instead? Like int8 and float32?

@JeromeRichard it really needs to be 64 bit.  I did wonder if it was memory bound but I think the speed up from AndrejKesely shows that isn't entirely true.

@Simd The code of AndrejKesely is memory-bound on my machine : it nearly saturates what my DRAM can achieve. I think it explains why the speed up is rather small. The serial code reaches 12 GiB/s while the parallel one reach 35 GiB/s (the max is generally ~36 GiB/s on my machine for RW benchmarks and 40~42 on RO benchmarks). Besides, both versions spend a significant time in page-faults (15-20%) decreasing performance.

@JeromeRichard Do you think it's as fast as it can get? I was wondering if avoiding making temp might help.

We can reduce the memory pressure of the implementation, but inputs need to be read and the output needs to be written and I think these things takes most of the time (>50%), hence my comment about reducing their size (especially the dtype).

@JérômeRichard I've removed the missing_maxes = np.empty_like(arr) allocation for additional speedup (from ~7 secs originally to ~2.3 sec)

I get ~70% speedup when I use parallelization in replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last():
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last_parallel(d):
    """
    Run max_bar_one on each row but the last, prepend an all -inf row
    """
    m, n = d.shape
    result = np.empty((m, n))
    result[0] = -np.inf
    for i in nb.prange(0, m - 1):                 # <-- using prange here
        result[i + 1, :] = max_bar_one(d[i, :])
    return result


@nb.njit
def main_function_parallel(d, subcusum, j):
    temp = replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last_parallel(d)  # <-- using parallel version of the function here
    for i1 in range(temp.shape[0]):
        for i2 in range(temp.shape[1]):
            temp[i1, i2] = max(temp[i1, i2], d[i1, i2]) + subcusum[j, i2]
    return temp


EDIT: Additional speedup is to remove missing_maxes = np.empty_like(arr) temporary allocation. In this case the speedup is 300%:
@nb.njit
def max_bar_one2(arr, result, to_compare, to_add):
    largest, second_largest = find_two_largest(arr)
    missing_maxes = result
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        if arr[i] == largest:
            if largest != second_largest:
                missing_maxes[i] = second_largest
            else:
                missing_maxes[i] = largest  # largest == second_largest
        else:
            missing_maxes[i] = largest

        missing_maxes[i] = max(missing_maxes[i], to_compare[i]) + to_add[i]
    return missing_maxes


@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last_parallel2(d, to_add):
    """
    Run max_bar_one on each row but the last, prepend an all -inf row
    """
    m, n = d.shape
    result = np.empty((m, n))
    result[0] = d[0] + to_add
    for i in nb.prange(0, m - 1):
        max_bar_one2(d[i], result[i + 1], d[i + 1], to_add)
    return result


@nb.njit
def main_function_parallel2(d, subcusum, j):
    return replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last_parallel2(d, subcusum[j])


Benchmark:
from timeit import timeit

import numba as nb
import numpy as np


@nb.njit(cache=True)
def find_two_largest(arr):
    # Initialize the first and second largest elements
    if arr[0] >= arr[1]:
        largest = arr[0]
        second_largest = arr[1]
    else:
        largest = arr[1]
        second_largest = arr[0]

    # Iterate through the array starting from the third element
    for num in arr[2:]:
        if num > largest:
            second_largest = largest
            largest = num
        elif num > second_largest:
            second_largest = num
    return largest, second_largest


@nb.njit(cache=True)
def max_bar_one(arr):
    largest, second_largest = find_two_largest(arr)
    missing_maxes = np.empty_like(arr)
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        if arr[i] == largest:
            if largest != second_largest:
                missing_maxes[i] = second_largest
            else:
                missing_maxes[i] = largest  # largest == second_largest
        else:
            missing_maxes[i] = largest
    return missing_maxes


@nb.njit(cache=True)
def replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last(d):
    """
    Run max_bar_one on each row but the last, prepend an all -inf row
    """
    m, n = d.shape
    result = np.empty((m, n))
    result[0] = -np.inf
    for i in range(0, m - 1):
        result[i + 1, :] = max_bar_one(d[i])
    return result


@nb.njit(cache=True)
def main_function(d, subcusum, j):
    temp = replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last(d)
    for i1 in range(temp.shape[0]):
        for i2 in range(temp.shape[1]):
            temp[i1, i2] = max(temp[i1, i2], d[i1, i2]) + subcusum[j, i2]
    return temp


@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last_parallel(d):
    """
    Run max_bar_one on each row but the last, prepend an all -inf row
    """
    m, n = d.shape
    result = np.empty((m, n))
    result[0] = -np.inf
    for i in nb.prange(0, m - 1):
        result[i + 1, :] = max_bar_one(d[i, :])
    return result


@nb.njit
def main_function_parallel(d, subcusum, j):
    temp = replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last_parallel(d)
    for i1 in range(temp.shape[0]):
        for i2 in range(temp.shape[1]):
            temp[i1, i2] = max(temp[i1, i2], d[i1, i2]) + subcusum[j, i2]
    return temp


@nb.njit
def max_bar_one2(arr, result, to_compare, to_add):
    largest, second_largest = find_two_largest(arr)
    missing_maxes = result
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        if arr[i] == largest:
            if largest != second_largest:
                missing_maxes[i] = second_largest
            else:
                missing_maxes[i] = largest  # largest == second_largest
        else:
            missing_maxes[i] = largest

        missing_maxes[i] = max(missing_maxes[i], to_compare[i]) + to_add[i]
    return missing_maxes


@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last_parallel2(d, to_add):
    """
    Run max_bar_one on each row but the last, prepend an all -inf row
    """
    m, n = d.shape
    result = np.empty((m, n))
    result[0] = d[0] + to_add
    for i in nb.prange(0, m - 1):
        max_bar_one2(d[i], result[i + 1], d[i + 1], to_add)
    return result


@nb.njit
def main_function_parallel2(d, subcusum, j):
    return replace_max_row_wise_add_first_delete_last_parallel2(d, subcusum[j])


def get_d_cumsum_rows(n):
    A = np.random.randint(-300, 400, (n, n)).astype(float)
    cusum_rows = np.cumsum(A, axis=1)
    d = np.random.randint(-300, 400, (n, n))

    return d, cusum_rows


n = 10
np.random.seed(42)
out1 = main_function(*get_d_cumsum_rows(n), 0)

np.random.seed(42)
out2 = main_function_parallel(*get_d_cumsum_rows(n), 0)

np.random.seed(42)
out3 = main_function_parallel2(*get_d_cumsum_rows(n), 0)

assert np.allclose(out1, out2)
assert np.allclose(out1, out3)

t1 = timeit(
    "main_function(a, b, 0)",
    setup="n=5000;a,b=get_d_cumsum_rows(n)",
    globals=globals(),
    number=100,
)

t2 = timeit(
    "main_function_parallel(a, b, 0)",
    setup="n=5000;a,b=get_d_cumsum_rows(n)",
    globals=globals(),
    number=100,
)

t3 = timeit(
    "main_function_parallel2(a, b, 0)",
    setup="n=5000;a,b=get_d_cumsum_rows(n)",
    globals=globals(),
    number=100,
)

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)

Prints on my computer (AMD 5700x):
7.003944834927097
4.12014868715778
2.2788363839499652


I get a similar speed up now.  I was hoping for i1 in range(temp.shape[0]) could be parallelized too.   Maybe temp shouldn't be made separately?

@Simd Looking at the code I guess (but it's just a guess) the bulk of time is spent in max_bar_one() function. But definitive answer would be to profile your code. Perhaps you can get rid of this allocation missing_maxes = np.empty_like(arr) and write to result directly (but the code has to be restructured). Maybe you can explain the algorithm, what is the goal of this script.

The problem is that I don't how to profile numba code.  This code forms part of a larger dynamic programming algorithm so it's hard to describe its purpose without the overall picture.  My guess is that the doubly nested for loop takes a reasonable proportion of the time, although probably not the majority.

for a quick "profiling" you could also call max_bar_one() twice, or run it only over the first half of the array

@Simd I've managed to remove the missing_maxes allocation, the speedup is now ~300% compared to original.

That's a great speed up!

I guess this is close to the best we can do based on the provided input

@Simd There is no way to profile easily a Numba code unfortunately (as opposed to Cython or a native code). You can add timings with the object mode but it is experimental and sometimes crash and cannot be used in parallel regions...

@JeromeRichard There is the new module called profila but I have had mixed results with it.

@Simd Good to know. That being said, it seems to be a very-new project supported by 1 person (created 3 month ago -- so with a good chance not to live long) and it does not support profiling parallel Numba codes yet (nor Windows, nor MacOS -- only Linux)... I wish the Numba team could support perf (standard way of profiling programs on Linux) which as been requested several years ago (despite being supported by LLVM)... Currently, they work on this.
